# ExpressJS : Understanding console log

Tags: node.js, express, http, status

I develop a server in Nodejs. After sending requests from browser, terminal in which I run Express server shows following log:

```
OPTIONS /api/auth/login 204 3.555 ms - 0
POST /api/auth/login - - ms - -
```

My question is, what happened to POST request, and why it is not processed properly with returning status 201?

Any help is apreciated!

Comment: can u share the code for the corresponding post request?

Comment: Sure, there is route code: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/6zcFSsNz